# Admob Mediation Do we need to change only Appid of Adview by mediationId or along with have to add SDK's also

Tags: android, admob

i have integrated Admob but i found the Add ad network under admob mediation so i have added the 4 other network,so will i have to just replace the Appid in Adview with mediation ID? or along with it i will have to insert all SDK's of those add network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to add the SDKs for those other ad networks as well as the mediation libraries for each, though a lot of the ad networks now ship their Admob mediation classes as part of their standard SDKs.